# How create queryset to custom fields?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-1.11

I have 2 custom fields as in the picture below in my form.

When user make `GET` request, in the right list I want to show user's permissions. In the left list I want to show available permissions which is not yet in right list. How to make correct queryset to my custom fields? I am confused.

Thats how I think I need to create queryset to `available_permissions` field. Pseudo-code:

```
for available_permission in Permission.objects.all()
   if available_permission not in (QuerySet <user_permissions>)
       Create new QuerySet with available_permission
```

1) How to know User's permisssions? I think here I need to send user id from view to form.

2) How create Empty queryset and add objects to that queryset?

**forms.py:**

```
class UserEditForm(UserChangeForm):
    available_permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
        queryset=None,
        required=False,
    )

    current_permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
        queryset=None,
        required=False,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.current_permissions = kwargs.pop('current_permissions')
        self.available_permissions = kwargs.pop('available_permissions')
        self.fields['current_permissions'].queryset = self.current_permissions
        self.fields['available_permissions'].queryset = self.available_permissions
```

**views.py:**

```
class UserEditView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'users/edit_user.html'
    form_class = UserEditForm
    model = User

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context = {
        'user': user,
        'user_edit_form': UserEditForm(
            instance=user,
            current_permissions=user.get_all_permissions(),
            available_permissions=Permission.objects.difference(user.user_permissions.all()),
        ),
        }
        ***
```

[image]

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Projects/web/dashboard.kase.kz/users/views.py", line 75, in get
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('users/edit_user.html', context, request=request)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 173, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 71, in __len__
    return len(self.subwidgets)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 57, in subwidgets
    for widget in self.field.widget.subwidgets(self.html_name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 56, in <genexpr>
    BoundWidget(self.field.widget, widget, self.form.renderer)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 561, in subwidgets
    for option in self.options(name, value, attrs):
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 566, in options
    for group in self.optgroups(name, value, attrs):
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 575, in optgroups
    for index, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(chain(self.choices)):
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1139, in __iter__
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 871, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/compiler.py", line 21, in as_sql
    with_col_aliases=with_col_aliases,
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 430, in as_sql
    result, params = self.get_combinator_sql(combinator, self.query.combinator_all)
  File "/Users/nurzhan_nogerbek/Virtualenvs/py2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 389, in get_combinator_sql
    raise DatabaseError('ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.')
DatabaseError: ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.
```

**UNION**:
**forms.py:**

```
final_available_permissions = Permission.objects.none()
for available_permission in Permission.objects.all():
   if available_permission not in self.current_permissions:
      final_available_permissions = final_available_permissions.union(available_permission)
self.fields['available_permissions'].queryset = final_available_permissions
```

**ERROR UNION:**

```
AttributeError: 'Permission' object has no attribute '_combinator_query'
```

Comment: You are asking 2 questions here. Please just submit one question at a time. It is possible to create an empty queryset with `model.objects.none()` and then add items to it using `QuerySet.union()` or the union operator `|`, similar to sets. But that is a rather roundabout and probably inefficient approach.

Comment: I tried to use `.union` method as you said but it raise error. =( Do you have any ideas? I also update post with code check it pls.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a user's permissions by `user.user_permissions.all()` and the inverse by `Permission.objects.difference(user.user_permissions.all())`. But if you have take into account group permissions as well, you have to do something more complicated.

An alternative solution, since there was problems with `QuerySet.difference()` in your setup.

```
current_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=user)
available_permissions = Permission.objects.exclude(user=user)
```

Comment: Can you check my post again pls? I update it with your code which you adviced but it raise error. Are you sure about `Permission.objects.difference(user.user_permissions.all())`? I use Oracle maybe this code dont work with Oracle or what? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `QuerySet.difference()` was added in Django 1.11. If you use an older version, you must use a different approach or upgrade.

Comment: I use Django 1.11 but Python 2.7.

Comment: Then I don't know what's wrong. What is the exception message?

Comment: Full log you can see in the post. ERROR part. `DatabaseError: ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.` It seems to me `.difference()` dont work with Oracle. =(

Comment: I think you are right. Looks like an oracle specific thing. You can try adding `.order_by()` to either of the querysets. With no arguments, it should clear previous ordering. Just a guess. I have no experience with oracle.

Comment: I've added a second suggestion to my answer that does not involve combining two querysets with `.difference()` or anything like that.